# Mounting a VBox shared folder as user

Tags: linux, virtualbox, permissions, mount, fstab

In my Windows host, I have an Arch linux VirtualBox guest.
I setup a Windows folder as a shared folder in VBox. I then manage to mount the folder as type vboxsf in my guest (done in /etc/fstab), but the owner is root, not my user.

How can I control who the owner of the mounted filesystem is?

`chown` did not work at all, not `chown -R` on the unmounted mounting point either.

Comment: I agree you will, most likely, find the solution to your problems in the above-referenced link.